# rename コマンドを使ったフォルダのリネームでエラー Substitution replacement not terminated at (user-supplied code)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Ubuntu20.04環境においてフォルダのリネームをしたいです。
renameコマンドが使えそうだったのでインストールし、
以下の様に実行しようとしましたがエラーが出ます。

```
rename "s/^20/" */
```

(年月日のフォルダ名の年を下2桁にしようとしています)

以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
Substitution replacement not terminated at (user-supplied code).
```

以下のコードも試してみましたが同じエラーが出ました。

```
rename "s/^20/" *
rename "s/^20/_" */
```

Comment: `/` が足りません。`rename 's/^20//' */`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename コマンドに限らず、正規表現を使う場合には以下のようなフォーマットで記述する必要があり、`/` スラッシュが三つ必要です。

```
$ rename 's/正規表現/置換後の文字列/' 対象のファイル名
```

やろうとしている事に当てはめると、余計なフォルダは無いものとして一番シンプルには次のようなコマンドになると思います。

```
$ rename 's/^20//' *
```

参考:
https://wiki.ubuntulinux.jp/UbuntuTips/FileHandling/RenameCommand

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました